# How to specify what to do if a Pester assertion fails?

Tags: powershell, pester

If you wanted to say, 1 should equal 1, and if it doesn't then break, what would be the most eloquent way to do this in powershell with pester avoid code duplication?

Eg

```
{1 | should be 1} else {break}
```

rather than

```
1 | should be 1
if (1 -ne 1) {break}
```

Comment: That... doesn't really make sense. If breaking instead of returning 1 is a valid response, then `Should Be 1` is not a good test for your thing

Comment: I think maybe they are asking if there's a good way to stop Pester from executing any further tests if a particular test fails.

Comment: @MarkWragg ahh, `break` from the test suite, that makes more sense :)

Comment: Perhaps I picked a bad example. I just mean, if an assertion fails, and you want to run some commands in the event of failure, is it possible to tack this onto a failed pester assertion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no built in functionality for breaking the test execution when a failure occurs at the moment, but it has been discussed here: https://github.com/pester/Pester/issues/360 with some wrokarounds such as this one:

```
BeforeEach {
    $FailedCount =  InModuleScope -ModuleName Pester { $Pester.FailedCount }

    if ($FailedCount -gt 0) {
        Set-ItResult -Skipped -Because 'previous test failed'
    }
}
```

Another option might be to break your tests up into several different Pester scripts. Then you could have some high level or initial tests that you check for success on first and if they have not all passed then you skip execution of the remaining test scripts.

For example:

```
$Failed = (Invoke-Pester -Path First.tests.ps1 -PassThru).FailedCount

If ($Failed -eq 0) {
    Invoke-Pester -Path Second.tests.ps1
    ..
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is built-in functionality for this now

https://github.com/pester/Pester/pull/2023

```
$pesterConfig = New-PesterConfiguration
$pesterConfig.Run.Container = @((New-PesterContainer -Path C:\Users\Armaan\Documents\powershell-dev\sample.Tests.ps1), (New-PesterContainer -Path C:\Users\Armaan\Documents\powershell-dev\sample2.Tests.ps1))
$pesterConfig.Output.Verbosity = "Detailed"

$pesterConfig.Run.SkipRemainingOnFailure = 'Run'
Invoke-Pester -Configuration $pesterConfig
```

Comment: This works great, you can even limit the skipped tests to a group of tests by setting `$pesterConfig.Run.SkipRemainingOnFailure = 'Block'`. E. g. if you group some tests by using `Context {}`, it will only skip the remaining tests of this block, but still executes more tests on a higher level.

Answer (score 0):

I landed here looking for a way to make one test have a dependency on another.

```
#Dependency in Pester v3.4.0, Windows-PowerShell v5.1
Describe 'testing pester' {
   It 'Check for legacy Pester version' {@(Get-Module 'Pester')[0].version | should be '3.4.0'}

   $dep = @{}
   context 'when in here' {
      It 'when the independent test fails' {
         $dep.aSpecificDependency = 'failed'

         'a' | should be 'b'

         $dep.aSpecificDependency = 'passed'
      }
      
      It 'then the dependent test is inconclusive' {
         if(-not $dep.ContainsKey('aSpecificDependency')){
            Set-TestInconclusive -Message 'aSpecificDependency did not run.'
         }elseif($dep.aSpecificDependency -ne 'passed'){
            Set-TestInconclusive -Message 'aSpecificDependency did not pass.'
         }
         'a' | should be 'a'
      }

      It 'it is also inconclusive when the independent has not yet been performed.' {
         if(-not $dep.ContainsKey('aDifferentDependency')){
            Set-TestInconclusive -Message 'aDifferentDependency did not run.'
         }elseif($dep.aDifferentDependency -ne 'passed'){
            Set-TestInconclusive -Message 'aDifferentDependency did not pass.'
         }
         'a' | should be 'a'
      }
      
      if($dep.ContainsKey('aSpecificDependency') -and $dep.aSpecificDependency -ne 'passed'){
         return
      }

      It 'stops before running this one' {
         'a' | should be 'a'
      }
   }

   context 'when looking at another section' {
      It 'goes fine' {
         'a' | should be 'a'
      }
   }

   if($dep.ContainsKey('aSpecificDependency') -and $dep.aSpecificDependency -ne 'passed'){
      return
   }
   context 'when looking at another section' {
      It 'or you could stop on that too' {
         'a' | should be 'a'
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: interesting, thanks Gregory

Comment: Most testing frameworks don't guarantee the order that tests run so I don't know if I'd trust this approach.

Comment: @penguin359 this is specifically for Pester, moreover an older version of Pester that shipped with Windows10 which does not have built in support for test dependencies

Comment: Sorry, that should probably be Windows Powershell v5.1 instead of Windows10

Comment: I don't think the `pester`, `describe`, `context`, or `It` commandlets would parse out the `[scriptblock]` objects passed in as parameters to run the SB's internals out of order; however the `pester` and `It` commandlets do accept an array of script objects so I could see where these may be processed out of order. (This has not been my experience so far)

Comment: My impression of Pester is that the `It` and `Describe` commands just create the tests as script blocks in some data structure and then they are executed all at once (though still in the same order at the moment). In fact, I suspect the `if` statement that it outside of the `It` blocks in the example above is running before any tests start. I just did a test on my local box and `Write-Warning` printed output before after after the `It` script block ran.

Comment: As for how Pester might get them out of order, while it seems like Pester v5 might be using an array data structure right now that retains their order, I can imagine a future where they decide a Hash Table makes more sense with the name being the `It` name string and the value is the test/scriptblock. In this case, it will enumerate over the name/value pairs in some indeterminate order based on their hash value.

Comment: @penguin359 I would not expect that the contents within the scriptblock given to the `context` or `describe` commandlets to be run in an out of order. I do see situations where it could become possible where the `It` statements when broken up into multiple blocks or their parameters could be processed out of order or in parallel, but you'd have to cross that bridge when you get there and this code with the `It`s all in one block shouldn't be subject to OOP. eg `{},{},{} | It` or `It @({},{},{})` sure, but `{It {}; It {}; It {}}` I don't foresee it happening.

Comment: Also note that the execution order is preserved, but the output to the screen is not because `It` has a postfix message unlike `describe` and `context`. `$x=@{v=1};function w{write-host ($x.v++)};w;describe 'd' {w;context 'c' {w;It 'i1' {w};w;It 'i2' {w};w};w};w`

Comment: or for example `$t={@(Get-Module 'Pester')[0].version | should be '3.4.0'};$c={It 'has the expected version' $t};$d={context 'on the commandline' $c};describe 'using Pester' $d`, I would not expect Pester to parse either `$c` or `$d` because  this would likely lead to breaking changes in `mock`.

Comment: @penguin359 huh maybe [it does both](https://github.com/pester/Pester/blob/acc66a965219a8e70981977289227a211af4c70e/src/Pester.Runtime.ps1#L517C28-L517C28)

Comment: I am not saying that the order within a script block is indeterminate. No, that is sequential from top to bottom. However, what we are talking about are one script block per test being added to a test suite in the outer script block. The tests don't execute at the point that the `It` function/cmdlet is executed. You can verify this by splattering the outer block with `Write-Warning` commands to see when they run. The script block passed to the `Describe` function/cmdlet runs to the end before the tests themselves are started.

Comment: You can see that all `It` does it just adds it as a `New-Test` here: https://github.com/pester/Pester/blob/acc66a965219a8e70981977289227a211af4c70e/src/functions/It.ps1 As it is currently written, it uses a List<> which guarantees ordering: https://github.com/pester/Pester/blob/acc66a965219a8e70981977289227a211af4c70e/src/csharp/Pester/Block.cs#L20 so the `if` conditionals inside the test blocks will run in the order of tests, but that `if` conditional at the `Describe` script block level still runs before any tests are started and is out of order.

Comment: @penguin359 ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ something changed between v3.4.0 and current, because I'm not getting the same results you're seeing. It looks like current [now has this built in](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76115131/4496560); so use that if you can, and if you can't you could give this a try... quick way to tell would be the `$x={v=1};fuction w`... example from above. May also want to add the pester version check test to fail and notify you that the tests may not be executed as expected on a different version of pester.

Comment: looks like it broke in v5, [see the 6th bullet](https://pester.dev/docs/migrations/breaking-changes-in-v5) about Discovery and Run.